# Queue for messages from two sources in Apache Camel with chronological order

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse

I would like to realize next scenario in Apache Camel (included in JBoss Fuse):

I have two systems, both of them produce events stored in database separately. Now I need to read events from this event tables and put them as messages in queue (realized by ActiveMQ). But what is really important I need to keep chronological order (creation time) of events in this queue, no matters where event was created.

I am looking for solution, which maximally uses components and patterns from Camel framework, of course I can realize the reading mechanism outside of Camel (pure Java), but I prefer Camel solution.

Thanks a lot for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to pop the messages onto a `seda` queue and use a `resequencer` to merge them back into order.

```
from("--database1--")
    to("seda:resequencer")

from("--database2--")
    to("seda:resequencer")

from("seda:resequencer")
    .resequence(header("date")).batch().timeout(5000L)
    .to("activemq:...")
```

You will need to pay attention to the timeout settings and what is appropriate.

(Note: I haven't tested this code, so please tage it as a suggestion).

Comment: It seems like to be a working solution, is it possible to detect (stop) processing messages, when one (or both) databases aren't available? I mean, when one of them is down, if I could stop passing through messages from the second.

Comment: Sure, I think you could use `onException` to then go to a new route where you in turn use `controlBus` to stop the other database route, or more simply just to set a boolean `keepProcessing` flag on a bean that is used in a filter in both routes.

Comment: +last point, not sure if the `seda:resequencer` is necessary, worth trying with `direct:resequencer` first.